# How do I search in intermediate table mysql

Tags: mysql

I have the following tables

```
player
-------------
idPlayer,
name,
age, 
position

Team
--------
idTeam,
name,
value
```

and the intermediate table:

```
team_has_player
-----------
idPlayer,
idTeam
```

What I need is to search in "team_has_player" with the variable "idTeam" and select all the players that are the ordered pair, summarizing, search for "idTeam" and show all the "Player" that have their "idPlayer" related to that "idTeam".

Comment: Please show us sample data and expected results, and also show us your current attempt at solving the problem.

Comment: Also it would be good if you could translate your schema to English, so it will be more talkative to people here, that do not speak your language.

Comment: Only foreign keys should contain the table name. Are you asking for a join?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this SELECT Statement

```
SELECT 
  e.nombre,
  j.nombre
  , j.edad
  , j,posicion
 FROM  `jugador/equipo` je 
 INNER JOIN Equipo e ON e.idEquipo = je.idEquipo
 INNER JOIN jugador j ON j.idJugador = je.idJugador
 WHERE je.idEquipo = 1;
```

It will show you, the name of the Club and the nam,e of the Players plus there Age and Position

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to know the ids from the player related to a team, this could work:

```
SELECT idPlayer FROM team_has_player WHERE idTeam = 2;
```

This will return a list with all the players in that team.

If you want to know more information like the names (or other info in the player table) you could do the following:

```
SELECT p.name, p.position FROM player p
JOIN team_has_player tp
ON tp.idplayer = p.idplayer
WHERE tp.team_idteam = 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not quite clear, what format you expect as output but you could try the following:

```
SELECT e.nombre nombre_equipo,
          GROUP_CONCAT(j.nombre) jugadores
FROM equipo e
INNER JOIN jugador_equipo je ON je.equipo=e.equipo
INNER JOIN jugador j ON j.idjugador=je.idjugador
GROUP BY e.nombre
```